# on click clone li with different li class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

on click clone li with add it under li with a class clicked and on click on different li the previous clone should get removed

for eg: what i would like to achieve is on the click of `<li><span>third</span></li>` clone same li under ul with a class "clicked" `<li class="clicked"><span>third</span></li>` && when i click on other li like `<li><h4>Fourth</h4></li>` the old li with class clicked should get removed and new li of `<li class="clicked"><h4>Fourth</h4></li>` should get generated

```js
$('li').click(function() {
  $(this).each(function(i) {
    $("<li>")
      .append($(this).contents().clone())
      .appendTo('#main-ul');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
<ul id="main-ul">
  <li><a href="">First</a></li>
  <li><div>Second</div></li>
  <li><span>third</span></li>
  <li><h4>Fourth</h4></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please clarify what needs to happen (instead of just one run on sentence) and clarify what the exact question/problem currently is.

Comment: @Scott Marcus what i would like to achieve is on the click of <li><span>third</span></li> show same li under ul with a class "clicked" <li class="clicked"><span>third</span></li> && when i click on other li like<li><h4>Fourth</h4></li> the old li with class clicked should get removed and new li of <li class="clicked"><h4>Fourth</h4></li>  should get generated

Comment: i have also updated the question

Comment: No, please edit your question so that it is clarified and add the code to your question.

Comment: i have updated...

Comment: Your requirement doesn't seem overly complicated given that you already know how to `.clone()` and set `.html(new_element)` - instead of .appendTo, use .html (as in your codepen - but only if going to a 2nd `ul`) - then `.addClass` to add `clicked`.   

Exactly which part are you having difficulty with?

Comment: Do you want the output in the same `main-ul`?  or a 2nd `ul`?

Comment: on the same ``main-ul`` @freedomn-m

Comment: If it's the same, then use .remove() and .addClass() - if it's different you can do a direct `.html(..clone..)` as in your codepen.  .remove/.addClass works for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you clone the element into the `ul` (the same, but doesn't matter), give it the `clicked` class with `.addClass` at the same time.

You can then remove all the ".clicked" elements when you add your next entry.

```js
$('li').click(function() {
   // remove previous entry (does nothing if none)
   $(".clicked").remove();

   // add new entry with class
   $(this)
      .clone()
      .addClass("clicked")
      .appendTo('#main-ul');
});
```

```css
.clicked { color: red; }

ul#main-ul > li { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
<ul id="main-ul">
  <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
  <li><div>Second</div></li>
  <li><span>third</span></li>
  <li><h4>Fourth</h4></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: hey why is it not working on jquery 1.12 how do I make it work on these versions? ``<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>`` rest everything is perfect thank you it works superb... @freedomn-m

Comment: There could be any reason it's not working with jquery*-ui* 1.12.  If you can create a snippet that includes jquery-ui and which parts are "not working" (eg not copying the style? not able to active after cloning?).  It's possible jquery-ui does some additional processing before your clone that won't be run after your clone.

Comment: any idea why this codepen is not working https://codepen.io/AnthonyDavid/pen/abJPYPd

Comment: Press F12 and look at the browser's console at the errors.  *Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined* If you include jquery-ui.js then you need to include jquery.js before it.

Answer (score 1):

This code is work for you if I understand what you want.

```
 <script>
        $('li').click(function() {
            
            $(".clicked").remove();
            $('li').each(function(){
            if($(this).children().length==0)
            {
                $(this).remove();
            }
            })
            $(this).each(function(i) {
            $("<li>")
                .append($(this).contents().clone().addClass("clicked"))
                .appendTo('#main-ul');
            });
        });
        </script>
```